# Retrieving Details of connected accounts of a contact in android

Tags: android-contacts, android-account

I am making a contact app in android. I am able to retrieve contact name,number, Emailid of a contact using "Cursor". 
When i click on contact it shows name,phone number and email id of that contact but i also want to show all connected accounts for that contact like "Gmail" and "Whatsapp" ,"Facebook","Yahoo" in it.
Is there any way to show all connected accounts for a contact in our app?
Thanx a lot in advance.